# pegar texto select e enviar form jquery

Tags: php, jquery

eu fiz essa função para enviar com jquery via post e tenho que pegar o value e o texto do select e mais um valor de um input type text. Segue o código abaixo

```
    function SalvarRegistro(){
    $(this).ready(function(){
        var cursodisciplina_id = $("#disciplina option:selected").val();
        var descricao = $("#disciplina option:selected").text();
        var link = $("#link").val();
        var usuario_lancamento = $("#usuario_lancamento").val();
        var adicionar = 1;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "cursodisciplinaemena_acao.php",
            data: {cursodisciplina_id: +cursodisciplina_id, descricao: +descricao, link: +link, usuario_lancamento: +usuario_lancamento, adicionar: +adicionar},
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data[0].msg);
            },
            failure: function() {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente!");
            }
        });
    });
    return true;
}
```

o cursodisciplina_id tá indo e o usuario_lancamento tbm,  mais o texto do select e o link que é um input type text não vão de jeito nenhum ficam com o valor NaN pelo firebug, não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: opeta, teria como compartilhar o código HTML também?

Comment: Qual é o critério que as pessoas estão utilizando para negativar, a pessoa que o fez poderia postar o motivo aqui? É uma pergunta completamente válida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

opeta,

fiz uns testes aqui e acho que descobri o problema.
Se você perceber, somente os seus valores do tipo `String` não estão sendo enviados. Isso acontece porque você está utilizando o `+descricao` ao inves de `descricao`.

Faça um teste, atribua uma string a uma variavel e execute a expressão `+variavel`, o retorno será `NaN`.

Então para o seu código funcionar, apenas remova o `+`:

```
 function SalvarRegistro(){
    $(this).ready(function(){
        var cursodisciplina_id = $("#disciplina option:selected").val();
        var descricao = $("#disciplina option:selected").text();
        var link = $("#link").val();
        var usuario_lancamento = $("#usuario_lancamento").val();
        var adicionar = 1;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "cursodisciplinaemena_acao.php",
            data: {cursodisciplina_id: cursodisciplina_id, descricao: descricao, link: link, usuario_lancamento: usuario_lancamento, adicionar: adicionar},
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data[0].msg);
            },
            failure: function() {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente!");
            }
        });
});
return true;
```

Comment: putz matou a pau eu já estava a 1 hora tentando compreender pq só as strings não eram enviadas vlwww.

Comment: a merito de curiosidade, porque você estava utilizando os +?